# Send message to Client with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to send a message from the server to a specific client.

This is my client class (console application)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/chathub")
            .Build();

        connection.StartAsync().Wait();
        connection.On("ReceiveMessage",(string message) =>
        {
            Console.Write(message);               
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My HubClass (asp.net mvc core)

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType> MyUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType>();

    public Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public Task SendMessageToUser(string connectionId, string message)
    {
        return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        MyUsers.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, new MyUserType() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId });

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserConnected", Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        MyUserType garbage;
        MyUsers.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out garbage);

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnected", Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
    }
}

public class MyUserType
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
}
```

Now how do I execute the `Console.Write(message);` in the console application from the web app?

I've tried doing something like this:

```
ChatHub chatHub = new ChatHub();
chatHub.SendMessageToAll("test");
```

but the `Clients` is null in the ChatHub class.

Comment: Hi @Fahad Jameel, what is your server like? Does it contain any view to send or receive the message? Besides, why your client only call receive method? It still needs invoke send method.

Comment: There's no send method because I don't need to send anything from the client to the server. I just need to send the clients a message from the Server (asp.net app)

Comment: Hi @Fahad Jameel, I have updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below in your server:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;      
    public HomeController(IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
    {
       _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public IActionResult CallClient()
    {
        //execute the client code
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "test");
    }
}
```